# Can I configure the output of microsoft sql server management studio? query + output window take up too much space

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ide

I am new to Sql Server.  One of the things that I am seeing is that I am writing a query in the top window and viewing results in the bottom window.  The problem is that the result of the query takes up a lot of space vertically.. some queries take up a lot of space vertically.

I want to see both the query and the query result side by side, or at least not stacked on top of one another.. Is there some option to do this?  Is there an alternate tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not stacking it side but side, but the short cut of Ctrl-r lets you show / hide the results window very quickly, and not bother moving the vertical divider.